# TideSDK app to send file to FTP server

Tags: tidesdk

I've developped a web page for sending file to a FTP server. It take the file, rename it, access a FTP server, create a directory and put the file in.

I'm looking for a way to make it working as a desktop app. Is TideSDK able to do that? I guess it could as I used PHP, HTML and JQuery. But does the TideSDK API allow to access FTP server?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was asking me the same thing. Using <*insert popular search engine name here*> I digged up something on the [official Github page of *TideSDK*](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Building-PHP-Language-Support).

It is possible to compile the TideSDK by yourself to include PHP's support for (in example) FTP in the PHP interpreter. Please refer to the [TideSDK wiki pages about compiling TideSDK](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Building-tidesdk) for other platforms than Linux like given in the example.